# Use node-restful with mongoose.createConnection

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

Two constraints: using `node-restful` and creating non-global connection (because of testing purpose) using `mongoose.createConnection`

Code below won't work:

```
var someSchema = require('./someSchema');
var restful = require('node-restful');
var model = restful.model('some', someSchema);
//far far away...
var connection = restful.mongoose.createConnection();
connection.on('connected', function() {
  restful.register(app, '/somes');
}
```

`GET /somes` causing infinite loop somewhere or not triggering callback. Anyway, [node-restful model.js code](https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful/blob/master/lib/model.js) shows no support for connection and model don't know anything about current connection. Does anybody know how to provide connection to model? I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in

https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful/blob/master/lib/model.js

I see that the code registers models with mongoose:

```
var result = mongoose.model.apply(mongoose, arguments)...
```

passing in the mongoose variable.

So node-restful always looks for a model registered on the default mongoose connection. The one you create by calling:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/resources");
```

You'll have to rewrite the node-restful code to allow passing in a connection instead of just using the mongoose instance. I'm not sure how easy or hard that will be do to.

Comment: And exactly that I would avoid, but if even you can't see other way... Well, I have to try.

Comment: Yep, it helps. It is not perfect solution, but maybe I will fix it later and give it as a pull-request. Thanks, your answer resolved problem! Fork: https://github.com/puradawid/node-restful